# Parsing Multiple JSON with Promise.all() Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, promise

Here is my use case:
- I have two URLs which I send the same input to fill a param
- I need to parse the JSON response and create a list from a key of the response.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function initialCall(input) {
  let urls = [
    `https://mybusinessendorsements.com/api/auth?token=0d34aa6dad5d50de697c62bdf8a633f4&industry=${input}`,
    `http://mybusinessendorsements.com/api_spn/auth?token=0d34aa6dad5d50de697c62bdf8a633f4&industry=${input}`
  ];

  let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
  Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => responses.forEach(
    response => alert(`${response.json()}: ${response.status}`)
  ))};

//[object Promise]: 200
//[object Promise]: 200
```

Im not sure how to get the the json array to print out to parse and manipulate as need, help!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`response.json()` returns another Promise [1], so you'll need to call `Promise.all` twice, like so:

```
Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
  .then(jsonObjects => /* ... */);
```

For readability you could introduce a helper function

```
Promise.all(requests)
  .then(toJSON)
  .then(jsonObjects => /* ... */);

function toJSON(responses) {

  if (!Array.isArray(responses)) {
    // also handle the non array case
    responses = [responses];
  }

  return Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()));

}
```

If you need to keep the reponse (state):

```
function resolveJSON(responses) {

  return Promise.all(
    responses.map(response => response.json()
      // will return an object with keys "response" and "json"
      .then(json => { response, json }))
    );

}
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json